# What is the canonical name for the identity type?

Tags: scala, category-theory, type-theory

I recently answered a question here: [How do I express this in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900619/how-do-i-express-this-in-typescript/36901745#36901745)

Here's the snippet of code from the above:

```
trait FooBar[M[_]] {
  val foo: M[Integer]
  val bar: M[String]
}

type Identity[X] = X
type A = FooBar[Identity]
type B = FooBar[Option]
```

I have seen this used couple of times:

```
type Identity[X] = X
```

But, what is the name for this (either the `Identity` type or this technique in general) in category theory literature? Is `Lift` a better name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, this is called an [*Identity Function*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function):

> In mathematics, an identity function, also called an identity relation or identity map or identity transformation, is a function that always returns the same value that was used as its argument. In equations, the function is given by f(x) = x.

The more formal mathematical definition is as follows:

> Formally, if `M` is a set, the identity function `f` on `M` is defined to be that function with domain and codomain `M` which satisfies: `f(x) = x` **for all elements x in M.**
>   In other words, the function assigns to each element x of M the element x of M.

If you're looking specifically for the category theory definition, this is called [Identity Morphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism). The wikipedia value talks about morphism composition and then describes the identity morphism as:

> **Identity**: for every object X, there exists a morphism id<sub>X</sub> : X → X called the identity